# How to pass android permission name as variable?

Tags: android, permissions

Which type of variable can pass `REQUESTED_PERMISSION` to the following function  (sample code from [Here](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting)) and how it shoud be concatenated to `android.Manifest.permission.`+ ?

**Edit:**

It seems that the variable should also pass through the `ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission` (It is marked as unused). How should I pass it?

```
Public boolean checkPermission( ????? REQUESTED_PERMISSION){

    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(
            CONTEXT, android.Manifest.permission.REQUESTED_PERMISSION) ==
            PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        performAction(...);
    } else if (shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(...)) {

        showInContextUI(...);
    } else {
        requestPermissions(...);
    }
}
```

Comment: Sheikh Ali you can use this: `android.Manifest.permission.PERMISSION_NAME`

Comment: How do you concatenate `PERMISSION_NAME` in that combination and what type of variable is it? @abstractArrow

Answer (score 0):

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission
Here you have list with the permissions. They are all strings.

```
public boolean checkPermission( String permission ) { ... }
```

usage (for example, you need vibration) :

```
checkPermission(Manifest.permission.VIBRATE);
```